# Swift CollisionBitMask values with SpriteKit not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I'm setting up basics physics tests for a prototype of a game I'm developing, but the collisionBitMask isn't working properly. I want the charSprite to collide with the floorSprite and NOT push it down into oblivion (because of gravity), so I assign the charSprite a categoryBitMask of Test1 and a collisionBitMask of Test2, and vice versa for floorSprite. This works fine when Test1 = 0 and Test2 = 0b10, but when I try changing the values of Test1 and Test2 to, say, 0b20 and 0b30 or any other values than 0 and 0b10, it doesn't work and the floorSprite gets pushed down to oblivion by the charSprite. This is a problem because I want more than just 2 categories for bit masks and only the values 0 and 0b10 work, and even then, it only works when charSprite has the categoryBitMask of 0 and collisionBitMask of 0b10 and floorSprite is 0b10,0. It doesn't even work when charSprite has a categoryBitMask of 1 and a collisionBitMask of 0 and floorSprite is 0,0b10! I can't find any values for my bit masks that work! Can anyone help me? Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

struct ColliderType {
    static let Test1:      UInt32 = 0
    static let Test2:        UInt32 = 0b10
}

var charSprite:SKSpriteNode!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    println("Running")

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -2)



    // Add sprites

    charSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "MainCharacterTest")
    charSprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2 - 300, y: self.size.height/2 + 200)
    charSprite.zPosition = 1

    charSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: charSprite.size.width, height: charSprite.size.height))

    charSprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    charSprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    charSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Test2
    charSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Test1
    charSprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Test1

    self.addChild(charSprite)

    let floorSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "testthing")
    floorSprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2 - 200)
    floorSprite.zPosition = -1
    floorSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: floorSprite.size.width * 1, height: floorSprite.size.height * 1))



    floorSprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    floorSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Test1
    floorSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Test2
    floorSprite.physicsBody?.contactBitMask = ColliderType.Test2
    self.addChild(floorSprite)


func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if let node1 = contact.bodyA.node {
        // charSprite.removeFromParent()
        // self.addChild(gameover)
    }

}

func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    // pass
}
}
```

Comment: instead of a struct, did you mean an enum?

Comment: No--the tutorial I learned from used structs. Should I be using an enum?

Comment: I just tried using an enum and it still doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with it a bit, I realized that I needed to set the dynamic attribute of the floorSprite to false. Sorry for the person who mentioned that earlier then deleted your comment--for some reason when I tried it the first few times it still wouldn't render right until I started from scratch. Now it works for any value for ColliderType.

Answer (score 1):

try setting the floor sprite's `collision bit mask` to 0. This *should* let both sprites NOT go through each other, but the floor will not move when the character lands on it

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem, though, because I want to have a bunch of different collider types and I want some of them to collide with each other and not others and I can't do that if I just rely on 0.

Comment: well you can declare different collision bit masks on other sprites that you need to collide with each other. But since you want the floor to not move, keep it at 0. Or in your struct set one of the variables values to 0 for the floor

Comment: So the only way to have a sprite not get pushed away is by setting its collisionBitMask to 0? That doesn't seem right. What if I want 2 different types of sprites to not get pushed around and have different collisionBitMasks?

Comment: lol idk man, I'm just trying to help with what you initially asked. This is what I know off the top of my head.